# How can linearize the product of decision variables in ILP?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

Here, we have something like this:

$$R + (1-R)T + (1-R)(1-T)S + (1-R)(1-T)(1-S)Q = 1$$

where $R$, $T$, $S$, $Q$ are binary decision variable

How can I convert this nonlinear summation of products to linear equation in much more simple way? I mean to have less constraints to have after linearization.

Comment: More simple compared to what? The standard linearization which would introduce three constraints and one variable per nonlinear term

Comment: The first thing I get to think about is Karnaugh diagrams. But as Johan writes below the terms are in this case complementary in a very specific way. If not R then next term come into effect iff T, if also not T then S and so on.

Comment: Yes, Karnaugh diagrams is one way to attack circuit minimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to do *circuit minimization for boolean functions*, at least to begin with.

Your function can be minimized to $R + T + S + Q = 1$. I used this [on-line minimizer](http://tma.main.jp/logic/logic.php?lang=en&type=eq&eq=%20R%2B~RT%2B~R~TS%20%2B%20~R~T~SQ) (although it easily can be seen by inspection in this case)

Edit: Your function in the comments, which is index to first nonzero element of a binary vector $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, assuming there is a non-zero element, can be described by introducing a new binary vector $s\in\{0,1\}^n$ (picking the position of first non-zero), and the constraints $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}s_i \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{k}x_i$, $k\sum_{i=1}^k s_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^k x_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n s_i = 1$, for all $1\leq k\leq n$. The index is then given by $\sum_{i=1}^n is_i$.

Comment: Thanks dear professor Lofberg for your nice answer.